# When I post my data to controller gives error [::1] refused to connect

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I post my data to controller in codeIgniter so gives an error:

`http://[::1]/new_ci/index.php/Admin/getData`

I get error.

> [::1] refused to connect.

Comment: DId you set `base_url` ..?

Answer (score 2):

It will most likely be that you have not got your base url set. 
This is a common thing people are not checking on.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

> ***Note:*** In some cases you do not have to like in older versions of
>   CodeIgniter. But latest versions CodeIgniter 3 and up I would recommend it.

And there for may show url's like below example:

`http://[::1]/your_project/`

`http://127.0.0.1/your_project/`

It is best I think to set your base url because you will run in to link errors even though may work on localhost in some cases may not work on live server.

application > config > config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```